# Xcode 4 - One Click Build to Multiple Devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xcode4, build

In Xcode 4 is it possible to somehow setup so that with one click of the 'Run' button in the top left have Xcode build to more than one device with one click?

It would save a lot of time, constantly having to click build to iPhone, then build to iPod, then iPad is irritating one after another. All in one click would be ideal.

An example of how this would be helpful is when building a universal app, where I want to quickly build and run on both my iPhone and iPad at the same time.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new target to your project: File -> New -> New Target... From `Other` category choose `Aggregate`. Then build that target which aggregates all other targets you're interested in.

P.S. Universal App is an app which is built from one target. Two targets are two apps.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. However with my universal build, I would like to build to both my iPhone and iPad with one click, using one target.

Comment: So that one target is `Aggregate`. It will build both targets with one click as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but I can't quite figure out what to do to actually have it build on both devices once I have made the new aggregate target.

Comment: Eimantas, could you expand your answer with how exactly you set up the `Aggregate` target for multiple-device-build? @JoshKahane, have you figured this one out? How did you do it?

Comment: [See "How to 'Build & Run' on multiple destinations at once in Xcode 4?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262553/how-to-build-run-on-multiple-destinations-at-once-in-xcode-4)