# Run on simulator and phone with one click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working on a chat-based app, and have been compiling/running the project first in Simulator, and then changing the device to my phone and then compiling/running there. This sets up two devices so I can test the chat between them.

This works fine but is slightly tedious as I'm doing it almost every time I compile.

Is there a way I can setup XCode so I can hit Run and it will compile and run on both devices with that one click?

Or has anyone come up with a more efficient solution for testing when two devices are needed?

Comment: There's this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040940/xcode-4-one-click-build-to-multiple-devices... But after adding an Aggregate target I have not yet figure out how to have that target build for both devices at the same time.