# Is it possible to run an app on two devices with one click on the build and run button in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, build, xcode5, device

Is it possible to run an app on two devices with one click on the build and run button?
E.g. I have an application that has to run on two devices to test some networking functions between the devices.

It is really annoying to select each device separately from the scheme selector and then click the "build and run"-button.

So I'd like to configure my build process to let the app automatically build and run on both devices. Is this possible? And if it is, how?

Versions: Xcode5, OSX Mavericks

---

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262553/how-to-build-run-on-multiple-destinations-at-once-in-xcode) Question but it doesn't seem to work anymore since I get the the following error message when I open the .app file:

```
You can’t open the application “Run” because the Classic environment is no longer supported.
```

Furthermore I can't select the .app file for the launch application service in the automator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible, but perhaps to speed it up, a quick keyboard shortcut:

Switch build target  HOLD: cmd + opt + ctrl THEN PRESS  [ or ] -- switches target

Then, build it with cmd + r

Not exactly what you're looking for, but should cut your time fairly significantly!

Comment: thank you logan. This workaround would help me a lot if no other solution is possible, but I'm not even able to switch the build targets manually as you described. I also had a look in the key bindings preferences and was not able to find a configuration option for this. How did you manage to setup this key bindings?

Comment: I didn't add anything, but maybe I didn't explain the shortcut well, I'll edit it.

Comment: I figured it out. This standard shortcut is not working for me because  it changes the scheme, not the destination. The shortcuts for switching the destinations are not even working (maybe because I have a German keyboard layout). I figured out how to change the key bindings for this commands. Now I'm able to change the destination with another shortcut I set up. It's not exactly what I like to have but I can work with it for now.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, I just double checked and it is changing the destination for me!  Glad you got something working, at least you don't have to click around!

Comment: I think it's because on my keyboard I have to use opt + 5 or 6 to get the [] brackets. this is why the shortcut was recognised as cmd + ctrl + ] or [

Answer (score 0):

Choose your Device at the top, build and run (Cmnd+R) and while running it, select a different device without stopping the other device, then build and run it again (Cmnd+R) on that device.

It definitely works with a real device and a simulator, but I don't know about 2 real devices.

Goodluck! :)

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my question. I know that this works and it works for two hardware devices too, but I'm looking for a solution to avoid the need to switch the targets manually.

Comment: oh okay i understand, sorry. I don't know that :(

Comment: ok, don't worry. thanks for you help anyway. hopefully someone else knows a solution :)